# Rails 3.0.17 sending inline attachments instead of regular ones

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer, email-attachments

So, we have just upgraded our project to Rails 3.0.17 (please don't ask why this particular version, just happened so) on top of Ruby 1.8.7 enterprise edition.

I have methods to generate CSV data and send it as a file via email.

```
# contact_mailer.rb
def send_payments_report
  attachments["report.csv"] = {
    :content => Payment.generate_csv_report,
    :mime_type => "text/csv"
  }

  mail(
    :from => "from@example.com",
    :subject => "Payments report",
    :to => "to@example.com"
  )   
end
```

Here's what it returns:

`=> #<Mail::Message:2231891440, Multipart: true, Headers: <Date: Wed, 19 Dec 2012 11:48:05 +0200>, <From: from@example.com>, <To: to@example.com>, <Message-ID: <50d18d555dcdc_2269838ab93812784@artem.local.mail>>, <Subject: Payments report>, <Mime-Version: 1.0>, <Content-Type: multipart/mixed; >, <Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit>>`

The email itself is displayed as plain text without attachments:

```
--
Date: Wed, 19 Dec 2012 11:48:05 +0200
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/csv;
charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: attachment;
filename=report.csv
Content-ID: <50d18d555dcdc_2269838ab93812784@artem.local.mail>

"customer id","reference nr","invoice id","invoice type","invoice sum","sum paid","payment date"
"1035","010294","7113","Fine","250.00","100.00","2012-11-15"
"1035","010294","6132","Fine","250.00","250.00","2012-11-15"
"1035","010294","5241","Fine","850.00","650.00","2012-11-15"
--
```

I tried attaching existing file, but it displays it the same way. It worked perfectly on Rails 2.3.9. Can anyone help on that?

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have solved this problem.
Here how I call the `mail` method:

```
mail(
  :from => "from@example.com",
  :subject => "Payments report",
  :to => "to@example.com"
) do |format|
    format.text {render :text => ""}
end
```